# Angular 5 - TypeError: _this.form.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that is basically just a list of data and a button that calls a popup. I have the same code structure on a few components with some names changed and they all work fine, it's just this one that seems to not want to play ball. I'm certain in missing something obviously missing just cant figure it out. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, this has really bothered me for days...

```
TypeError: _this.form.get is not a function
at forms.js:6831
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at FormGroupDirective._updateDomValue (forms.js:6830)
at FormGroupDirective.ngOnChanges (forms.js:6648)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12092)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13598)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13541)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14413)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14354)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (DatabaseListComponent.html:27)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14339)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)
at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:13790)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13514)
at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:13816)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13509)
at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:13790)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13514)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:14740)
at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:14277)
at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:11300)
at core.js:5786
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at ApplicationRef.tick (core.js:5786)
at core.js:5619
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:513)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4629)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:512)
at Zone.run (zone.js:263)
at NgZone.run (core.js:4446)
at Object.next (core.js:5619)
at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:4223)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at EventEmitter.Subject.next (Subject.js:55)
at EventEmitter.emit (core.js:4203)
at checkStable (core.js:4594)
at onLeave (core.js:4673)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4623)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:545)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:313)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:620)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1661)
at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1687)
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { DatabaseService } from "@app/+database/database.service";
import { NewDatabaseModel } from "@app/core/models/new-database-model";
import { DatabaseListModel } from "@app/core/models/database-list-model";
import { HostListModel } from "@app/core/models/host-list-model";
import { HomeListModel } from "@app/core/models/home-list-model";

@Component({
    selector: 'appc-database-list',
    templateUrl: './database-list.component.html'
})
export class DatabaseListComponent implements OnInit {
    showModal: Boolean = false;
    databaseForm: FormGroup;
    database: NewDatabaseModel;
    databaseList: DatabaseListModel[];
    hostList: HostListModel[];
    homeList: HomeListModel[];

    constructor(
        public fb: FormBuilder,
        private databaseService: DatabaseService,
    ) {
        this.databaseForm = fb.group({
            'serviceName': [null],
            'oracleHomeId': [null]
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadData();
        this.loadReferenceData();
    }

    loadData(): void {
        this.databaseService.getDatabaseList()
            .subscribe((res: any) => {
                this.databaseForm = res;
            });
    }

    loadReferenceData(): void {
        this.databaseService.getHostList()
            .subscribe((res: any) => {
                this.hostList = res;
            });
    }

    onHostnameChange(event: Event): void {
        var hostId = parseInt((event.target as HTMLSelectElement).value);
        this.databaseService.getHostOracleHomesList(hostId)
            .subscribe((res: any) => {
                this.homeList = res;
            });
    }

    saveDatabase(database: NewDatabaseModel) {
        this.showModal = false;
        this.databaseService.newDatabase(database)
            .subscribe((res: any) => {
                this.loadData();
            });
        this.databaseForm.reset();
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<h2>Databases</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Service Name</th>
            <th>Hostname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let d of databaseList">
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ d.serviceName }}</td>
            <td>{{ d.hostName }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showModal = true">Add Database</a>

<form [formGroup]="databaseForm" (ngSubmit)="saveDatabase(databaseForm.value)">
    <clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="showModal">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Add Database</h3>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ServiceName" class="required">Service Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="ServiceName" placeholder="ServiceName" formControlName="serviceName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Hostname" class="required">Client</label>
                <div class="select">
                    <select id="Hostname" (change)="onHostnameChange($event)">
                        <option *ngFor="let h of hostList" value="{{ h.id }}">{{ h.name }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Home" class="required">Home</label>
                <div class="select">
                    <select id="Home" formControlName="oracleHomeId">
                        <option *ngFor="let h of homeList" value="{{ h.id }}">{{ h.path }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" (click)="showModal = false">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
        </div>
    </clr-modal>
</form>
```

Module:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ClarityModule } from 'clarity-angular';

import { routing } from './database.routes';

import { DatabaseService } from "./database.service";
import { DatabaseListComponent } from "@app/+database/database-list/database-list.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        routing,
        ClarityModule,
        HttpModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DatabaseListComponent
    ],
    providers: [DatabaseService]
})
export class DatabaseModule { }
```

Comment: Does this `loadData` return a `FormGroup`?

Comment: No it doesn't, as as pointed out below I was putting the results of the service call into the wrong object. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `res` is a `FormGroup` this assignment can cause problems:

```
this.databaseForm = res;
```

Perhaps what you wanted to do is:

```
this.databaseList = res;
```